# Dynamic Object creation in a Form from a datatable c#

Tags: c#, forms, oracle, object, datatable

First of all sorry because I am very very new in programming, even more in C#. I have got a major problem in the way I am attacking this problem and the how to solve it with my capabilities. I have a database where I want to extract some data through a SQL query and I want to represent it in a group of buttons, every one of them having the data of the extraction. I would like this button to be dynamically created but because of my ignorancy I am going in circles.
I read a lot of things about the DataGridViews and so but I don't get a realistic way to do it (realistic for me of course).

What I achieved is to create a code that can read this DB and put the data in a datatable, once I have that I believed I can use this as a intermedial step to create a Form in VS where I can create the objects reading this datatable, creating a button containing the info inside (and maybe showing it through a datatiptool or something), one per "box" in the datatable and showing it "like" a datatable but with buttons which will be interactuable.

So, my code to create the datatable works and I have a table of 8 x 12 --> 96 positions, but how can I read this and create the buttons in a sort of "grid" of buttons?

Any help or tips would be very appreciated,
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. What would the database contain as data? What is that you are presenting through buttons? Is 8 * 12 constant and data contains the captions for the buttons? If so then simply you would put 8 * 12 buttons on form and set their Text property from data (only reading and setting Text part is dynamic then).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The data would be simple strings that I in my code appended in every single "box" of the datatable. Well considering my knoledge I am thinking about doing it as a constant but I know it would be better to be an adaptable code no matter the size og the grid... I am gonna try the "duDE" solution avoiding the creation of my datatable in the middle. Maybe I can use some of it mixing it so it would create the buttons grid instead of my table...

Comment: If it is dynamic like that, then you better use a grid. And also why would you create button controls? Instead you could code for CellClick event in the grid. With that approach your code would be much simpler (otherwise you should also think that you are coding Click event individually per button which is not needed at all).

Comment: Maybe you are right but I need the appearance of a plaque of compartments, all the same of each other, with for example different colours in them depending of the string info tath is contained in them (if error red and so on...) Then I am thinking in buttons because I can keep the info in the tool tip and show it at a click in a box or something like that. Probably is not the more efficient way to to it but I actually did something similar to that in VBA and I am trying to apply it in C#. That's the key in all of it: I am trying, I wish me luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, basically it's simple:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
    int nX = 0;
    int nY = 0;

    con.Open();

    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SomeTable", connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //create buttons
                    Button newButton = new Button();

                   // now set the DB properties
                   newButton.Text = reader.GetString(0): // or whatever

                   // now calculate the X and Y coordinates
                   nX += 25;
                   newButton.Location = new Point(nX,nY);

                   // add new button
                   this.Controls.Add(newButton);  
                }
            }
        } // reader closed and disposed up here

    } // command disposed here

} //connection closed and disposed here
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to do this and mix with the condition I created with the datatable creation. Maybe I can then create the grid of buttons with the same principle of the table, whcich is ultimatelly what I need. I will try and see if I can do it. Thank you!